# Return array of key=>value pair using Lambda in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have the following Lambda expression that returns an array of result properties:

```
ViewBag.Items = db.Items.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Column1, m.Column2 }).ToArray();
```

This works as expected, but I need the result to be a key=>value pair with Id being the key with Column1 & Column2 being the values. I've found examples on how to create a Dictionary, but not with isolating only specific columns in the results.

`ViewBag.Items` is localized for jQuery in the View using:

```
var _items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Items));
```

How do I change the Lambda above to make an array of key=>value pairs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it with `ToDictionary`:

```
db.Items.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Column1, m.Column2 })
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Id, x=>new {x.Column1, x.Column2});
```

That gives you `Dictionary` with `Id` as key and `{Column1, Column2}` as Values, if you want have Id as Value to consider good solution of HimBromBeere

Comment: I think the `.Select()` can be skipped

Comment: @Eric It might, but better **not** to be skipped if this is not LINQ to Objects (as it seems). In case `db.Items` is a database table, the `Select` will retrieve only the fields needed while the direct `ToDictionary` call will retrieve the whole record.

Comment: @IvanStoev It is a good catch, I have tried in LINQPad to confirm, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Where is the problem?

```
ViewBag.Items = db.Items.Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string, MyType>
    ( 
        m.Id, 
        new MyType { Column1 = m.Column1, Column2 = m.Column2 }
    )).ToArray();
```

But anyway a `Dictionary` is nothing but a list of `KeyValuePair`, so why not use it?

```
ViewBag.Items = db.Items.ToDictionary(
        m => m.Id, 
        m => new MyType { Column1 = m.Column1, Column2 = m.Column2 });
```

Of course you can also use a `Dictionary<anonymous, anonymous>`:

```
ViewBag.Items = db.Items.ToDictionary(
        m => m.Id, 
        m=> new { m.Column1, m.Column2 } );
```

but as you´re assigning this to a view I doubt you could use anonymous types here.

Using a `Dictionary` over an array of `KeyValuePair` has the advantage that duplicate keys are also checked. If you want to avoid this use `ToLookup` instead which will aloow duplicate keys.

Comment: The reason not to use a dictionary is because you are loosing deferred execution. If for instance you only want the first three elements, or the only one with a certain predicate, then the Linq statement with Select will stop as soon as your request is fulfilled. The statement with the dictionary will first put all elements in a dictionary and then perform your request. Waste of time if you only want FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse You´re also loosing deferred executing when calling `ToArray`, so this isn´t relevant.

Comment: At the end, none of the posts answer how you can create **array** of `KeyValuePair<IdType, AnonymousType>` w/o using `Dictionary`. And why not use it - well, because for some reason you need **array**. And why not use `ToDictionary(...).ToArray()` - because `ToDictionary` is redundant and inefficient if all you need is **array**. Anyway, it's funny to see "you could do this", "you could do that", but not how to do what I want if I was the OP :)

Comment: @IvanStoev See my first answer. It doesn´t deal anonymous, but obiously OP can´t use that anyway as he/she is using it directly within the view. Basically what OP asks is non-sense, why do you want an array of `KeyValuePair`? Either you build a dictionary from it or a lookup, I can´t imagine any other valid case for this so the anwesrs just deal with those *valid* cases.